# How to use Twilio SendGrid Java Helper Library with azure functions?

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, sendgrid

I am using SendGrid as the output of one of my azure function. And I am sending the same email to multiple users with the help of personalization. The code is as follows

```
@FunctionName("ehprocessor")
public void eventHubProcessor(
        @EventHubTrigger(name = "msg", eventHubName = "", connection = "eventhubConnString", cardinality = Cardinality.ONE) String eventHubMessage,
        @SendGridOutput(name = "message", dataType = "String", apiKey = "sendGridAPIKey", to = "jithin@mailinator.com", from = "jithin@vinnovatelabz.com", subject = "Event From The Machine", text = "Sent from Azure Functions") OutputBinding<String> message,
        final ExecutionContext context) {
    final String toAddress = "jithin@mailinator.com";
    final String toAddressMail = "jishnu@mailinator.com";
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder().append("{")
            .append("\"personalizations\": [{ \"to\": [{ \"email\": \"%s\"},{ \"email\": \"%s\"}]}],")
            .append("\"content\": [{\"type\": \"text/plain\", \"value\": \"%s\"}]").append("}");

    final String body = String.format(builder.toString(), toAddress, toAddressMail, value);

    message.setValue(body);
}
```

As you can see I am using the Json body to personalize the things. but now I want to use the helper library for sendgrid provided by java. How can I use it. Can somebody give me a code snippet of that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Twilio SendGrid library to send Email in java  by following the below steps:

If you are using Maven then add this dependency in `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sendgrid</groupId>
  <artifactId>sendgrid-java</artifactId>
  <version>4.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Create a new class called `SendGridEmailer` in your project with the following content:

```java
import com.sendgrid.*;
import com.sendgrid.helpers.mail.Mail;
import com.sendgrid.helpers.mail.objects.*;

import java.io.IOException;

public class SendGridEmailer {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

       Email from = new Email("test@example.com");
       Email to = new Email("test@example.com");

       String subject = "Sending with Twilio SendGrid ";
       Content content = new Content("text/html", "and Sending with Twilio SendGrid <strong>Java</strong>");

       Mail mail = new Mail(from, subject, to, content);

       SendGrid sg = new SendGrid(System.getenv("SENDGRID_API_KEY"));
       Request request = new Request();

       request.setMethod(Method.POST);
       request.setEndpoint("mail/send");
       request.setBody(mail.build());

       Response response = sg.api(request);

       System.out.println(response.getStatusCode());
       System.out.println(response.getHeaders());
       System.out.println(response.getBody());
   }
}
```

Here, API key is read from an environment variable.